# java8, optional.orElse() not working but optional.orElseGet() work

Tags: java-8

This is my code:

```
return repository.findFirstByFxDateAndTransCurrAndCrdhldBillCurr(
            LocalDate.parse(request.getDate()), request.getTransactionCurrency(), request.getBillingCurrency())
            .orElse(getCurrencyExchangeRateFromApi(request));
```

it not work, but I update .orElse to .orElseGet

```
return repository.findFirstByFxDateAndTransCurrAndCrdhldBillCurr(
            LocalDate.parse(request.getDate()), request.getTransactionCurrency(), request.getBillingCurrency())
            .orElseGet(() -> getCurrencyExchangeRateFromApi(request));
```

It's work perfectly, I don't know the reason, is that bug of java8 ?

I try to run again many times, nothing change, but I try to write an small example, optional of String instead of from repository, it's ok too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as Eran mentioned, there is a difference between `orElse` and `orElseGet`, no matter what the `Optional` is the method directly invoked in `orElse` will be **executed** while the `orElseGet` will invoke the `supplier` if and only if the `optional` is `null`.

Here is a small demo:

```
public class TestOptional {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Optional<String> val = Optional.ofNullable("Hello");
        String s = val.orElse(test());
        System.out.println(s);
        s = val.orElseGet(() -> test());
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static String test() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world
Hello
Hello
```

Answer (score 7):

In `.orElse(getCurrencyExchangeRateFromApi(request))`, `getCurrencyExchangeRateFromApi(request)` is always executed (regardless of whether the `Optional` is empty or not).

In `.orElseGet(() -> getCurrencyExchangeRateFromApi(request))`, `getCurrencyExchangeRateFromApi(request)` is only executed if the `Optional` is empty.

If by "not working" you mean you are getting an exception, perhaps there is a problem with your `getCurrencyExchangeRateFromApi(request)` method.